# A question about break statement in c programming

Tags: c, loops, break

I wrote this loop to add numbers, and the `break` to get out of the loop if the number entered is less than zero, and in last print the calculated numbers without adding the negative number.  but the problem is even I wrote the `break` statement before the addition when I enter 15 and 15 and -2 the output is 28 rather than 30
I found out how to fix that, what I want to know is why
and thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int j = 1, num = 0, rslt = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (num < 0) break;
        printf("enter a number : ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        rslt = rslt + num;
    }
    printf("the resluts are %d\n", rslt);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are effectively testing the input of the previous iteration, after already adding it to your result. Instead, check the number immediately after the user enters it, before you perform any calculations.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num = 0, rslt = 0;

    while (1) {
        printf("enter a number : ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        
        if (num < 0)
            break;
                               
        rslt += num;           
    }                          
                              
    printf("the results are %d\n", rslt);
}
```

You might also want to check that `scanf` returns the number of successful *conversions* you were expecting (in this case one), to handle the event where the user enters invalid input.

```
if (1 != scanf("%d", &num))
    break;
```

Comment: thank for answering Ia m a beginner I copied your code and I added rslt =0 after break and rslt += num and I entered 10 and 10 and -2 and the result became 0 that's why I think that break statement skip every thing but the operations it skip only one if it's right after it can you clarify plz

Comment: @UnderScore `rslt = 0` is going to reset the entire sum to `0` on every iteration. `rslt += num;` is the same as `rslt = rslt + num`. `break` immediately terminates the entire `while` loop. If you want to skip the rest of the current iteration, and move to the next one, you can use the `continue` keyword.

Comment: yes thank you so much for keeping up with me but break terminates the loop after evaluating the operation is that right

Comment: @UnderScore [`break`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/break) terminates the loop *immediately* - no further code in the block is executed. In `while (1) { puts("Hello"); break; puts(" world"); }`, only `Hello` will be printed.

Comment: thank very much for your help if I have other question I will ask again thanks

Comment: @UnderScore You are welcome. Please read [*What should I do when someone answers my question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), as you may want to accept this answer to show to others that your issue is resolved.

Comment: I will do that thanks